# How to convert Rcode to function - error

Tags: r

Hi I am trying to manipulate data after importing csv file using passing parameters to function as below

```
myfunc =function(x) {
  setwd = ("mydir")
  library(RMySQL)
df = read.csv(x,header = T ,sep = ",")
male = df [which(df$gender == "m"),]

#MALE
male$total_sal <- male$salary+male$increment
male$percentage = male$total_sal/male$salary

#FEMALE 
female = df [which(df$gender == "f"),]

female$total_sal = female$salary+female$increment
female$percentage = female$total_sal/female$salary

conn = dbConnect(MySQL(),user="user",password="mypw",dbname="mydb",host="localhost")
system.time(dbWriteTable(conn,"male",male,append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,overwrite=FALSE))
system.time(dbWriteTable(conn,"female",female,append=TRUE,row.names=FALSE,overwrite=FALSE))

dbDisconnect(conn)
}

myfunc("df.csv")
```

The error i am getting is :

> "Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") ":

Comment: Does the file exist in the working directory? Do you have the appropriate access permissions?

Comment: `In addition: Warning message: In file(file, "rt") ":` Perhaps that warning message is important. If so, what is it?

Comment: Can you assign the file name with complete path to `x` and try running the inner lines of your function one by one. You can tell us which line of code is giving error message.

Comment: getting same error after  changed the T to ","

Comment: @san1 please can you try the method I told you in the previous comment. Try to debug it line by line and check the value of each variable. Then let us know which line is throwing the error.

Comment: @Rui i have changed the file name correctly,now code is running good but i am unable to see list dataframes creted by function in global environment

Comment: @san1 `data.frames` created are within the scope of my_func. They will not exist outside the function until declared as global variables. Hence, you will not be able to see their names in the global environment.

Comment: You must return the data frames, something like `list(male, female)` as the **last line** of the function.